# JavaScript ECMAScript 6 - ERROR: "You can only use decorators on an export when exporting a class"

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I am trying to export a function in ECMAScript 6 so I can import it and use it in other files to have [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.

However, I receive the following error:

> You can only use decorators on an export when exporting a class (16:0) while parsing file:

```
@idempotent
export function totalItems() {
    this.cart.items.forEach((dish) => total += item.qty);
    return total;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using Babel? If so, please specify and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Using Ionic2, Doesn't matter as Babel just only complies the code..

Comment: Isn't this error *coming from the compiler*? It looks like it's defined in Babel's source code. Do the lines above this define a decorator, which you need to include? It's easier to help if you provide [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do so in the future.

Comment: Decorators are not ES6. They are a proposal for future versions of ECMAScript, which some compilers have chosen to implement in inconsistent non-standardized ways (making your choice of compiler extremely relevant). Per [the proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators), they are only going to be supported for classes, not standalone functions. That's your problem. But this post doesn't even include the code responsible for the error (no decorators are visible). This post will need to go on hold until/unless it can be made complete.

Comment: @JeremyBanks what you said is right; however, can you suggest a way in which I can share the same come with several files, instead of copying/pasting the same code in all the files?

Comment: @JamesRunner Do what you are doing now, and then in another file you could do: import { totalItems } from './location/to/total-items/file'

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o I'm already doing the import and receiving that error!

Comment: what's in the line before this export. Are you actually trying to decorate that / a function?

Comment: @JamesRunner You agreed with Jeremy Banks just now, he told you what the problem is. That error is not related to the import and export, it's something else in your code, likely not relevant to what you posted.

Comment: Your `item` variable seems to be undefined and you are not using the `dish` parameter.

Comment: This question is really intereresting. Because the `class` sugar syntax is just a "sugar". so we must have a way to do it without using the `class`. We are in a functional programming language but because of those new proposal, we are forced to use class. For me it sound like a break down in the logic of functional programming.

Answer (score 7):

What you're trying to do is not supported. The [decorator proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators) (which is not yet standardized) only includes @decorators for classes definitions and their methods, not for function definitions.

You may want to create a function decorator/wrapper function to be used like this instead:

```
export const totalItems = idempotent(function() {
    let total;
    this.cart.items.forEach((dish) => total += item.qty);
    return total;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export a function then you must add into the specific class like this:

```
export class GeneralFunctions
{
     totalItems() {
         this.cart.items.forEach((dish) => total += item.qty);
         return total;
     }
}
```

And at the place you want to use that function, simply import that class and create an object of it and call that function with the object like this:

```
import {GeneralFunctions} from "./<your-file>";

var obj : GeneralFunctions 
obj.totalItems();
```